# получение флага клавиатуры Assembler

Tags: ассемблер, клавиатура, dos, tasm

Мне нужно проверить, была ли нажата клавиша insert, num lock, и зажатие клавиш left shift и right shift.
Делаю так:

```
push ax
mov ah, 02h
int 16h
test al, 10000000b
jnz exit2
pop ax
```

и соответственно для остальных: test al, 00100000b, test al, 00000010b, test al, 00000001b

но это всё не работает (((

Comment: Какая среда исполнения кода? ОС?

Comment: в дос боксе, через tasm

Comment: Что значит "не работает". Какое значение возвращает int16h ? И что у вас находится на метке exit2, надеюсь там то же есть pop ax

Comment: я почитал в интернетах и нашёл, что в регистре al находятся байты флагов клавы, и мне в зависимости от того установлен флаг insert или нет нужно перейти по метке exit2, в данном случаем мне переход если insert включен, а exit2: pop a, и выход

Comment: мне по факту просто необходимо проверить нажатие insert, numlock, shift (left и right), в данном случае я пишу обработчик прерываний

Comment: вот здесь находил такую инфу, но она не работает: http://www.programmersforum.ru/showthread.php?t=165751

Comment: а здесь есть более детеальная информация о int 16h и битовом поле http://www.frolov-lib.ru/books/bsp/v02/ch2_4.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кароче, здесь всё верно, оно правильно работает, ошибка была походу в том что при первом вызове программы сначала обработчик прерываний записывался а потом выписывался из системы